# Best Practices for Converting PDF to Plain Text and Indexing with Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, openai-api, azure-openai

I am currently developing an in-house bot application using AzureOpenAI. My approach is to upload the company's manuals to Blob Storage, create a search index using Cognitive Search, and have the bot answer questions based on the content of these manuals. However, it's not working as expected. When I query the content of the uploaded files, I receive responses indicating that the content could not be found. I suspect that the search index is not being correctly created from the PDF files.

Therefore, I've decided to first convert the PDF data to plain text, and then create a search index with Cognitive Search. (To note, the actual PDF data contains multiple newline characters for human readability, representations with icons, and when converted directly to text, the result is quite messy.)

I would like to know if there are any specific points to consider when converting PDFs to plain text. Also, if there are any best practices for creating a search index using Cognitive Search, I would appreciate if you could share them.

For reference, here is some of the preprocessing I am doing right now (part of the code):

```
def preprocessing_text(text_path):
    with open(text_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        content = file.read()
        
    # Step1: Remove all newline characters and concatenate
    content = content.replace('\n', '')
    # Step2: Replace periods with a period followed by a newline
    content = content.replace('。', '。\n')
    # Step3: Remove all spaces
    content = content.replace(' ', '')

    with open(text_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(content)
```

Comment: Check deployments' status if it's succeeded?

Comment: Did you find a solution already? If so, please add it as an answer because I'm facing the same issues

Comment: Same problem here for PDF, it only works for text. We can read everywhere that PDF should work, but it seems to me it only import the same text as when you open a PDF in notepad